Basic Java: Exiting While Loops Preemptively
Hello beginner here in Java! I am currently doing a simple Quiz / Game show while using While Loops and If statements for learning experience. Unfortunately, I am stuck implementing a Health Point system to it because the if statement that's responsible for stopping the loop preemptively if the hp decreases too much, can't read the HP decreasing whatsoever and the statement that supposedly detects the wrong answers and makes HP decrease somehow don't work. This is a basic format of my code:
int Value = Number;
while(true) 
//or 
while(Value == Number) {

    //Question and Answer String
    
    System.out.println("Question");
    String Input = Scanner.nextline();
    
    //To check if the Answer is right or wrong
    
    while(true) {
        //Answer is Correct
        if (Condtion) {
            System.out.println("Something");
            break;
        //Answer is Wrong
        } else {
            System.out.println("Something");
    
            //Reduce the HP Here
    
            Value -= 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    
    //Question is repeated 5 times
    //Question is continuous even if one question got wrong answer but resets after 3 tries
    
    //If Statement for Losing all HP 
    // Ask to either quit playing or reset to the first question
    if(Condition to stop the loop the moment HP decreases to zero)  {
        System.out.println("Something");
        String Input = Scanner.nextline();

        //Answer is No
        if(Condition) {

        //Answer is Yes
        } else if (Condition) {
          //Repeat Question Format

        //Answer is something else
        ] else {}
    
    
    }

}
//After answering all questions once, statement appears if you want to continue playing or not
System.out.println("Something");
String Input = Scanner.nextline();

//Answer is No
if(Condition) {

//Answer is Yes
} else if (Condition) {

//Answer is something else
] else {}

If my code is confusing, I'll post the actual codelines I've used to better visualize the error in my code.

"If my code is confusing, I'll post the actual codelines I've used to better visualize the error in my code." Please post a [mcve].

Java naming conventions suggest you avoid capital letters at the start of a variable.

@GrindingForReputation A link to the conventions would be helpful for OP.

while(true) {if (X) {Y; break;} else {Y; break;}} can be written as just Y;, you can skip the loop and condition.

@teapot418 While OP has Y in both cases here, he clearly doesn't mean to print "Something" in both cases. Those are placeholder strings.

But still, if both branches of an if end with break; it’s a clear sign that the loop is obsolete. So instead of while(true) {if (X) {A; break;} else {B; break;}}, use if(X) { A; } else { B; }

You look like you have a C# background. Non-constant fields in Java should begin with a lower-case letter (per convention).
